# Why do I get different answers from css and xpath selectors?

Tags: css, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to scrape the following link using scrapy. [cpuc website document](https://docs.cpuc.ca.gov/SearchRes.aspx?DocFormat=ALL&DocID=389148419)

There is a table on that page, the values of which I am trying to scrape. When I scrape using xpath, it gives the correct answer. eg `response.xpath("//td[@class='ResultTitleTD']/text()").getall()`

gives

`['Comments filed by Southern California Gas Company on 06/24/2021 Conf# 167430', 'Proceeding: A2011004', 'Comments filed by Southern California Gas Company on 06/24/2021 Conf# 167430 (Certificate Of Service)', 'Proceeding: A2011004']`

as expected but when I run `response.css("td.ResultTitleTD::text").getall()`, I get an empty list as answer.

[image]

Why are css and xpath selectors giving different answers for the same query?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use invalid CSS locator.
You can use `td.ResultTitleTD` as a valid CSS selector, get those elements and then extract their texts but you can't use `td.ResultTitleTD::text` as CSS selector to access those lements texts directly.
UPD:
Here is the dev tools screenshot where I see those 2 elements located and highlighted using the above CSS selector
[image]

Comment: td.ResultTitleTD also returns empty list

Comment: I have checked this and saw 2 elements matching. Exactly as for `//td[@class='ResultTitleTD']` XPath

Comment: Hey, sorry if you find this stupid, I have added a picture in my post. Can you please guide where I am going wrong?

Comment: No, it's not stupid and I even don't know this occurs, but I see them in the dev tools as I added the screenshot in the updated answer

Comment: the data in table is loaded in table using javascript. If you disable javascript, the table doesn't filled. (the data is still available in response) but does not get shown in table. Do you think, it has any role in this discrepancy?

Comment: I prefer not to say what I don't know. Sorry. Maybe you need to add some delay before getting the response? But still, I don't know.

Comment: Give [this link](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#constructing-selectors) a go @Prophet. That is literally how to parse text using css selector in scrapy. Given that it's `::text` a valid use case.